# A way to search AD-Users based on DistinguishedName

Tags: powershell, scripting

Is there a way to search for AD-Users with their DistinguishedName?

Im working on a Reporting script which scans for all groups and exports to csv. Now my problem is when i access "MemberOF" from Get-ADGroup properties im only getting distinguished names and they are not so nice to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) documentation and the `-SearchBase` or `-Filter` parameters. (Examples 1 & 2)